# Binding a checkbox to Shared User Defaults

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I am building a table to display some data in my preferences pane. All of the data lives in NSUserDefaults. There is a checkbox in the table that will enable/disable data for the listed device. The checkbox is the only cell that is editable.

The table is correctly displaying the data from the Shared User Defaults. So I know that I have the table content properly mapped to the correct Shared User Defaults Model Key Path. However, when I toggle the checkbox, the new data is not being written to the defaults at all.

Here is a glimpse at the checkbox setup...

[image]

I have tried assigning a selector action to the NSButton (checkbox), thinking that I could set the default programmatically. Oddly enough, the action never gets triggered. I setup a simple action that just did an NSLog. It never got fired when clicking the checkbox.

**Update**: So that you can see what my defaults data structure look like, here is the output from the defaults command. There isn't really any code behind this table.

```
{
    ClimateDeviceData =     (
                {
            deviceName = Nest;
            deviceSetting = "76";
            display = 1;
            structure = Home;
            uuid = d01AA02AB145204VR;
        }
    );
    ClimateLoginAtLaunch = 1;
    ClimateMenuBarIconStyle = "Nest Temp Settings";
}
```

**Update #2**: At this point I would accept a solution on simply being able to invoke a selector from the Check Box.

Comment: It's not clear at what level you have bound the tableview cell view to the data but is it possible you need another level higher? ClimateDeviceData.display?

Comment: The Table View is bound to Shared User Defaults Controller and the Model Key Path has been set to 'ClimateDeviceData'.

Answer (score 1):

Should you not bind the `NSButton` (checkbox) to the `Shared User Defaults Controller` instead of what it is pictured, the `Table Cell View`?

Comment: I tried doing that for a long time and could never even get the data to be displayed at all. I do bind the Table View to Share User Defaults Controller though.

Comment: In cell-based tables you should always bind to the *column*, not the cell.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing roughly the same thing in an app. Not exactly, but basic principle is the same. A table populated with bindings, and a button in there (Can be a check box or another button, doesn't matter).

I tried the action on the button, but it didn't work either, so at the end, I used KVC concept.

- I use an arrayController in the XIB referencing a mutable array in my code that stores several instances of a custom object that has a status property (boolean).
- The view based tableview is bound to the arrayController using the arrangedObjects controller key.
- The button is bound to the tableCellView (the arranged objects), using that keyPath: objectValue.status (effectively fetching the status property of the custom object on that line).

In my controller code, I use the following lines to create the mutable array holding the custom objects:

```
  smartApp *appFound = [[smartApp alloc] initWithApplicationIdentifier:key];

  if (appFound)
  {
      [appFound setStatus:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

      [appFound addObserver:self
                 forKeyPath:@"status"
                    options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |
                             NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
                    context:NULL];

      [_appsArray addObject:appFound];
  }
```

I add an observer on the 'status' keypath of that object. And I add the pending code, observing the object for value changes:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)anObject
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context
{
    if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[smartApp class]])
    {
        if ([keyPath isEqual:@"status"])
        {
            NSLog(@"Clicked on row: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.appsArray indexOfObject:anObject]);
        }
    }
}
```

Once you're in the method, you can do what you want. It will definitely get called, and you get the object matching the line you clicked on, the change dictionary, and the keypath.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's different for view-based table views. (I'm just learning this myself.) In a view-based table view the Table Cell View's objectValue is the object represented by that row. You bind your text field, checkbox, etc. to keypaths of that objectValue.